# Cannot connect to websocket when using capybara and docker-chromedriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, capybara, actioncable

When running through capybara test, my tests fail when I need a response from a websocket, this pops up in the console.log:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:3001/cable' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

I am using the docker-chromedriver image.
The driver version is: ChromeDriver 2.46.628388
I am running a rails site with actioncable for websockets.

The server is set to accept requests from anywhere so I don't think cors is causing a problem. Here is the config:

```
   config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/*/, /https:\/\/*/]
```

In the development environment everything works. When I run an acceptance test using the chromedriver my test works until I get to the section that needs to use actioncable and then the test fails.

Has anyone come across this type of error before, or potentially have an idea on why the front-end cannot connect to the ws? From the tests I can see that the rails server is correctly triggering actioncable from the logs.

Comment: Is your app under test really accessible on 127.0.0.1 from the docker containers perspective?? Seems like that really should be trying to hit whatever ip your machine running the tests on is from the docker containers perspective.  Also what server are you having Capybara use, and are you mounting actioncable in process in the test environment?

Comment: I have the chrome driver running on my host computer. I have my server box serving  mapped through mapping port 80 on the host to port 3001 on the docker box(which is the port rails is being served on.) After that, I am using `Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome` with the `url` attribute set to the server on the host box so that the browser on the host is called and can hit `127.0.0.1`. The web calls work, ie navigation, ajax, but actioncable seems unable to connect.

Comment: I ended up finding out that redis was being used as the cable adapter and for tests it was being mocked out. It still hasn't fixed my problem but it was something I hadn't originally considered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being that I was letting all domains pass through on http, the protocol should have been ws.

```
   config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/*/, /https:\/\/*/]
```

Should have been:

```
   config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/ws:\/\/*/, /wss:\/\/*/]
```

Comment: Even though you did add the answer on April 1st I'd rather see you helping out then off :/